# Matlab - Gui very slow under Kubuntu

Tags: linux, performance, matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

There is the situation. I developed a GUI using GUIDE under Windows 10 to read videos and graphics at the same time. The GUI allows to navigate through the video and the graphics are correlated with the video.

To read the video I created a reader outside the main loop. At each turn I read a new frame and set reader.Cdata to display it.

1. Creation of the reader:

   ```
   I = imread(handles.fullPathname);
   handles.reader = imshow(I,'Parent',handles.axes1);
   handles.axes1.Visible = 'off';
   ```
2. Update the reader. I do the following steps at each turn of my loop:

   ```
   % --- Get the current frame, display it and set axes properties
   I = imread(handles.fullPathname,handles.numFrame);
   % Update the reader
   set(handles.reader,'Cdata',I);
   handles.axes1.Visible = 'off';
   pause(0.001);
   ```

I have to display and refresh at each turn of my loop also 3 graphics. I open a .txt file outside the loop and store in matrix all I need. then I plot at each turn of my loop the portions of graphics I am interested on.

---

Under Windows 10 I can display videos with a maximum framerate of 70f/s but now I am running under Kubuntu I can only display the video with a framerate of 10-15f/s...

I already try to increase the Java Heap Memory to 5012Mb to be sure it is not the problem but the situation didn't change.

---

This is some informations about the system and Matlab:

- Os : Linux 3.13.0-71-generic
- KDE SC : 4.13.2
- ROM : 64Go
- Processor : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU * 8
- Version of Matalb : R2015a
- Version of Java : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

---

Is somebody has/had the same problem and know a way to fix it ? I don't want to create by myself a GUI because I am an intern and I am running out of time...

Thank you !

Comment: You're basically doing GUI updates as fast as you can (although I'd use `drawnow` rather than `pause(0.001)`) so I'm going to guess that the real slow-down is the `imread` call within the loop. Why can't you read all frames in outside of the loop?

Comment: I don't read all the frames outside the loop to not saturate my Rom. In fact the video I want to display has a size of 50Go. When I was working on my computer I couldn't read all the frames so that's why !

Comment: Try putting a `tic`/`toc` pair around the `imread` and the `drawnow` command to see which is actually taking longer.

Comment: `imread` : Elapsed time is 0.022828 seconds.

`drawnow` : Elapsed time is 0.153949 seconds.

Comment: What is weird is that if I replace `drawnow` with `pause(0.001)` I have the same problem...

Comment: Yea so the rendering is just slow. As for why this is, there are potentially many reasons so it's hard to say specifically for your system.

Comment: And the refresh of all plots takes : 0.04 seconds...

Comment: You just said it took 0.153949 seconds... (plots aren't *actually* updated until you call `drawnow` or `pause`)

Comment: How can I have a better rendering. I think it is not a problem with the machine which is super super powerfull !

Comment: And why it is also faster under windows ..?

Comment: @AntoineMaugein, Just an idea: Matlab uses OpenGL under Windows which might not be supported by your Linux? de.mathworks.com/products/matlab/choosing_hardware.html

Comment: Matlab under my Linux is using OpenGL